# Restore deleted file in old local commit

Tags: git

I have local branch. I write new files, change some other and delete one file by mistake. Commit.

Again write code (new/change files). Commit.

No push.

I want to remove deleting file in my first commit.
I do not want amend second commit to restore deleted file.

Can anybody help me? I have no ideas.

**My solution:**

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2    
[Change for first commit 'pick' to 'edit']
git reset HEAD^    
[Revert deleted file]
[Add other files and commit]
git rebase --continue
```

Comment: Lets see if understand you: you want to revert a deletion of file in a certain commit without re-adding it again.

Comment: Yes, I do not want create third commit or amend second commit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git checkout <id-of-commit1>~1 path/to/the/deleted/file
git commit --fixup <id-of-commit1>
git rebase -i --autosquash
[it opens editor, check that the rebase plan is correct, exit the editor to proceed]
```

Comment: Do we should use "git rebase -i --autosquash", not "git rebase -i --autosquash <id-of-commit-before-commit1>"?

Comment: @YShinkarev It depends. Usually if you use simple branching/cloning, the default works fine, so you don't need to specify more args to rebase. But you could if you want to be more precise or something is unusual.